Any way to update displayed range in Google sheets?
I have a header section with 3 hyperlinks to different areas of the sheet.
Header
As I jump to each section, I would like to update a value (or some other way) that I can use to conditional format the header (the active range word is black text, the other 2 are gray).
I have tried onChange() but that only seems to trigger when I add/remove rows.
onEdit will not work since I do not edit anything to jump to that section.
Getting the active range is one way of doing it, but how do I trigger that to work on link click ?
I have tried the activate() function in apps script, but it takes too long to trigger (around 3-4 seconds).
Any ideas I missed ?
Thanks
edit:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLub0PcCpeqtae3Ut8Up6sU2OLOPA8ULvVD7MfT46mk/edit#gid=0
I have linked a file with a proof of concept.
Each Section cell at the top has a link to a section on that tab.
What I need is that if that if a section is displayed (for example section 2 - green), the cell in the header Saying Section 2 would turn green.
If section 3 (blue) is displayed, the cell in header with Section 3 will turn blue.
Same with clicking the link in each cell -> if it jumps to section 2, the cell with Section 2 in the header would turn a different color (green)

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand a header section with 3 hyperlinks to different areas of the sheet and As I jump to each section, I would like to update a value (or some other way) that I can use to conditional format the header (the active range word is black text, the other 2 are gray).. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Show your code. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLub0PcCpeqtae3Ut8Up6sU2OLOPA8ULvVD7MfT46mk/edit#gid=0
After you click a link, it jumps to a different color. I want the link cell for that section to change color when that section is displayed. Example: If section 1 is displayed, section 1 link cell is red. If section 2 is displayed, the link cell is green. If section 3, the link cell is blue

Try:
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  if (range.getRow() === 7
    && (col === 1 || col === 2 || col === 3)) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(7, 1, 1, 3).setFontColor("grey");
    range.setFontColor("black");
  }
}

Result:

onSelectionChange(e)
setFontColor(color)

Hi,
Not sure why your onChange works and mine does not.
Either way, this will not work since I need the link buttons to change AFTER you click the link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLub0PcCpeqtae3Ut8Up6sU2OLOPA8ULvVD7MfT46mk/edit#gid=0

Hi. It's hard to say since I haven't seen your implementation.

"I need the link buttons to change AFTER you click the link." This is new information. I think it should be added to the main post, not a comment.

copy the code into the question itself

Do I understand correctly that if you add up your initial wishes with those added later, then in your task there are now not 2 colors (black and white), but already 5 (black, white, blue, red and green)?

The colors do not matter, they are there to make it easier to understand. The file I shared has 2 onChange functions. One is manually set as a trigger and it works on interaction with the zone. The other should just color a background red (it does not work)
I just need to color the top buttons any color when that section is visible

Yes, it's not about the number of colors, but about changing the rules of the game on the go. Initially it was about changing the text color (“the active range word is black text, the other 2 are gray”). Now you are talking about changing the background color ("color a background"). So I'm trying to understand, is this new data instead of old, or in addition to it?

So I really appreciate your interest, but you understood the question wrong. The question was
"As I jump to each section, I would like to update a value (or some other way) that I can use to conditional format the header (the active range word is black text, the other 2 are gray)."
I need to update a VALUE based on the RANGE I am taken to when clicking the link. The colors (background, font) do not matter. I need a value with the RANGE (or ROW) I am at after clicking the link

There is a bug with onChange events. They will only work on refresh.
I ended up with this code:


function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  row = range.getRow()
  if (row < 50 && row > 4) {
    sheet.getRange("H2").setValue(row)
  } else if (row < 100 && row >= 50) {
    sheet.getRange("H2").setValue(row)
  } else if (range.getRow() >= 100) {
    sheet.getRange("H2").setValue(row)
  }
}



This updates H2 with the current active row. Based on that value I conditionally format the text in the header.
